# How to make tkinter label updatable and how to submit the entry value when pressed enter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I was making a gui app using tkinter and i want a label to be updatable
I have a list of words and i tried using a for loop to loop through all the list
It worked without tkinter but when i used tkinter only one word was being printed

```
 from tkinter import * 
 import random
 used = []
 
 words = ['car','dog','ball']
 plural = {
  'car' : 'cars',
  'dog': 'dogs',
  'ball': 'balls'
    }
 root = Tk()
 while i < len(words):
         word = random.choice(words)
         prompt = Label(root,text='what is the plural of the following word?')
          #i want currentWord to be updatable 
         currentWord = Label(root,text=word)
         answer = Entry(root,width=20)
         prompt.pack()
         currentWord.pack()
         def myClick():
                if answer.get() != '':
                   if answer.get() == plural.get(word):
                        myLabel = Label(root,text='Correct')
                        myLabel.pack()
                    else:
                       myLabel = Label(root,text='wrong')
                       myLabel.pack()
          myButton = Button(root,text='submit',command=myClick,bg='green')
          answer.pack()
          myButton.pack()
          root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What does this function `plural.get(word)`

Comment: It gets checks if the word matches the key in the dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the snippet if this is what you are looking for.

`config` is used to access an object's attributes after its initialisation.

For example, here, you define
`currentWord = Label(root,text="Answer")`

but then you want to set its `text` attribute,

so you use config:`currentWord.config(text=answer.get())`

Same goes for `prompt label` too.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
words = ['word1','word2','word3']
def myClick():
    if answer.get() != '':
        if answer.get() in words:
            currentWord.config(text=answer.get())
            prompt.config(text="Correct")
        else:
            currentWord.config(text=" ")
            prompt.config(text="Wrong")

currentWord = Label(root,text="Answer")
currentWord.pack()
answer = Entry(root,width=20)         
answer.pack()
prompt = Label(root,text='Status')
prompt.pack()
myButton = Button(root,text='submit',command=myClick,bg='green')
myButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit 1**
I think there is no need for `list` as you are entering through `entry widget` and searching in dictionary.

```
plural = {
  'car' : 'cars',
  'dog': 'dogs',
  'ball': 'balls'
    }
def myClick():
    if answer.get() != '':
        if answer.get() in plural.values():
            currentWord.config(text=answer.get())
            prompt.config(text="Correct")
        else:
            currentWord.config(text=" ")
            prompt.config(text="Wrong")
```

**Edit2**

If you loop through the list then if random word didnt match then your condition will fail. Hence I used an infinite loop.

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
words = ['car','dog','ball']
plural = {
  'car' : 'cars',
  'dog': 'dogs',
  'ball': 'balls'
    }
def myClick():
  while True:
    word=random.choice(words)
    print(word)
    if answer.get() != '':
        if (answer.get() in words) and(answer.get()==word):
            currentWord.config(text=plural[answer.get()])
            prompt.config(text="Correct")
            break
        elif(answer.get() not in words):
            currentWord.config(text=answer.get()+" does not exist")
            prompt.config(text="Wrong")
            break
        else:
          pass
currentWord = Label(root,text="Answer")
currentWord.pack()
answer = Entry(root,width=20)         
answer.pack()
prompt = Label(root,text='Status')
prompt.pack()
myButton = Button(root,text='submit',command=myClick,bg='green')
myButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer please recheck the question i added full code

Comment: @пулеметабду Please check the edit. I think you dont need a list

Comment: I used the list for the random module so it get a random word from the list

Comment: @пулемет абду then what is use of `entry` if he want to get a random value from `list`

Comment: I think the Entry is just to let the user to type stuff

Comment: @пулеметабду sorry but i guess there is something in appropriate in your question. please clarify it.. `entry` , `list`, `dictionary` and also `random` to just search a single word? i feel something is wrong

Comment: ok let me explain i used list of words then used random module to get a random word then print it to the screen if the entry entered by the user matches the value key pair from the dictionary then it is correct and the entry is like an input i guess  **btw can you tell me how to loop through all the elements in the list pls**

Comment: @пулеметабду `for i in words:` `print(i)` this will give you all elements in list. If you find my answer helpful please accept it as an answer

Comment: I was talking about tkinter i know how to loop through list in normal way

Comment: Thanks but it is telling me that word is not defined when i try to pack it

Comment: @пулеметабду I posted my full code now in edit2 and it works well for me. Please use it

Comment: Thanks man i appreciate your answers now its working although i had to edit some stuff in the code